# Attributes in Nested Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I'm trying to get two attributes from:

```
<% for location in @trip.locations %>
<%= location.address %>
<% end %>
```

and put them in the method to calculate distance between them:

```
<% @distance = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(address1, address2) %>
```

I was trying to use f.e @trip.locations.first(1) but I was receiving only the first letter of these two adresses and I couldn't fit in in method (wrong number of arguments - 1 for 2)

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @trip.locations.each do |location| %>
  <%= location.address %>
<% end %>
```

This will iterate over all `@trip`'s locations and print them out.

In Ruby you don't use for loops. Read about iterators in Ruby.

To get first location from `@trip` you would do:

```
@trip.locations.first
```

To get last location:

```
@trip.locations.last
```

Calculate the distance between these two:

```
<% @distance = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(@trip.locations.first, @trip.locations.last) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the locations, tracking the last location so you have it for calculating distance with the current location.

```
<% last_location_address = nil %>
<% @trip.locations.each do |location| %>
  <% if last_location_address
    <% distance = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(last_location_address, location.address) %>
    <%= distance # this line outputs the distance %>
  <% end %>
  <% last_location_address = location.address %>
<% end %>
```

But this is a lot of code for a view... I'd be tempted to do the calculations in the controller to create a distance array for the view.